# The same storyboard looks different on iPhone 4S and on iPhone 5

Tags: ios, retina-display, xcode-storyboard

I'm developing and iPhone application with XCode 4.5.2 and latest SDK.

On project settings I set 5.0 as Deployment target.

I'm very new on iPhone 5 development and I don't know how to use the same storyboard for iPhone 4S and iPhone 5.

Using storyboard with Retina 4 form factor I get this when I run my app on Simulator with Hardware -> Device -> iPhone (Retina 3.5-inch) setting:

[image]

This is what I get (I've uncheck use autolayout).

**How can I do to make it looks well on iPhone 4S?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use iOS 6 you could use [AutoLayout](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#recipes/xcode_help-interface_builder/articles/AutolayoutEditing.html).

To support the Retina Screen and the normal screen in iOS 5 you need to design the view for one screen size and then in your code programmatically check wether its the correct screen size

```
CGRect screenBound = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
CGSize screenSize = screenBound.size;  
CGFloat screenWidth = screenSize.width;
CGFloat screenHeight = screenSize.height;
```

When it's not the correct screen size you need to rearrange the UI elements by code.
It's bad but there is no other way to do this with 1 storyboard file.

The other possibility is to create a second storyboard file for the other screen size and in the app delegate check the screen size to determine which storyboard file you are going to use. (This can also be done with one storyboard file for iOS 5 and one for iOS 6, so that you can enable AutoLayout in the iOS 6 storyboard to support all screen sizes)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've asked another question related to this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14383058/constraint-to-add-more-space-between-two-uiviews