# Constraint to add more space between two UIViews

Tags: ios, retina-display, autolayout

I'm developing an iPhone application with XCode 4.5.2 and latest SDK.

Now I'm using Autolayout to work with one storyboard and use it with iPhone 4S and iPhone 5.

This is how can you see it with Retina 3.5 form factor:

[image]

And this is how you can see it with Retina 4 form factor:

[image]

I need to add more space between **Todos los establecimientos** and **Todos los products**. And also, between **Todos los products** and **Por distancia >**.

**Todos los establecimientos** and **Todos los products** now have a `Top Space to: Superview` constraint.

**How can I do to add more space between those elements when I use Retina 4 form factor?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done via a constraint with less than 1.0 Priority. 
To create a constraint between 2 views select both and click on the constraint button in the lower right corner of the interface builder to select the constraint you need in this case vertical spacing..

Raywenderlich has a good tutorial on this:
[Part 1](http://www.raywenderlich.com/20881/beginning-auto-layout-part-1-of-2)
[Part 2](http://www.raywenderlich.com/20897/beginning-auto-layout-part-2-of-2)

Or read Apples documentation:
[Apple Guide - Understanding Constraints](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-interface_builder/articles-autolayout/UnderstandingAutolayout.html)

Comment: Thanks for your answer but, do you know a tutorial about how to solve the same problem that I have? At this moment it is so difficult to understand Auto Layout and use it to solve my problem.

Comment: You need to add a constraint concerning vertical spacing and give a priority to them. In the sessions from WWDC 2012 there is a good sessions about auto layout. But I would really advice you to just try out setting the constraints an reduce their priority. Auto Layout always tries to fit as many constraints as possible. The one with highest priority first and so on.

Comment: I could share with you my storyboard (and viewcontroller) because I don't know how to do it. Send me an email if you want. You can find it on my web page (I don't know if I can write down my email here).

Comment: @VansFannel there's no simple magic hammer that will solve a problem with Autolayout. Spend a day or two to figure out how it works properly or you're in for a world of pain. If you haven't got the time or patience then don't use it for now. It's not compulsory.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the "Busqueda por filters" label and the "Por valoracion" labels to maintain their fixed distances to the top and bottom (respectively), then you could embed "Todos los establecimientos", "Todos los products", and "Por distancia" in a view. Those three items will have fixed spaces to the top, middle and bottom of that view. Give that view vertical spacing constraints to the "Busqueda por filters" label above, and "Por valoracion" label below, and remove any spacing constraints to the top or bottom of the main view. When the screen size gets bigger, this view will stretch giving more space between its views.